# How to find all maximum elements in a scalaz.Foldable container

Tags: scalaz

[scalaz.Foldable](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.Foldable) has a maximumBy method that finds *a* maximum element in a container. But is there an elegant way to find them *all* using scalaz? ie:

```
Vector(Person("Ben", 1), Person("Jil", 3), Person("Bob", 3)).maximumsBy(_.age) 
== Vector(Person("Jil", 3), Person("Bob", 3))
```

I have a problem where, if there are several equal maximum values, I want to select among these candidates randomly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like that

```
implicit def MaxNonEmptyListSemigroup[A : Order]: 
  Semigroup[NonEmptyList[A]] = new Semigroup[NonEmptyList[A]] {
  def append(l1: NonEmptyList[A], l2: =>NonEmptyList[A]): NonEmptyList[A] =
    Order[A].apply(l1.head, l2.head) match {
      case GT => l1
      case LT => l2
      case EQ => l1 append l2
    }
}

// returns None if the list is empty
// otherwise returns Some(non-empty-list of maximum elements)
list.foldMap1Opt(a => NonEmptyList.nels(a)) :: Option[NonEmptyList[A]]
```

Comment: There is another variation. You can also define a `Monoid[List[A]]` collecting the maximum as a `List` of elements and returning an empty list when there are no elements. In that case you would use `foldMap` instead of `foldMap1Opt`.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, `maximumsBy` will return the maximums in the same type of container as was provided. To do this efficiently seems to require [scalaz.Reducer](http://docs.typelevel.org/api/scalaz/nightly/index.html#scalaz.Reducer), a typeclass that models append- and prepend- to a container.

```
import scalaz._
import Ordering._
import std.AllInstances._

object Maximums extends App {

  def maximumsBy[F[_]: Foldable, A, B: Order](fa: F[A])(f: A => B)
                (implicit r: Reducer[A, F[A]]): Option[F[A]] =
    Foldable[F].foldMapLeft1Opt(fa)(a => (f(a), r.unit(a))) {
      case (curr@(max, maxes), a) => {
        val next = f(a)
        Order[B].apply(next, max) match {
          case GT => (next, r.unit(a))
          case LT => curr
          case EQ => (max, r.snoc(maxes, a))
        }
      }
    }.map(_._2)

  println(maximumsBy(Vector(("a", 1), ("c", 3), ("c", 3)))(_._2))
  println(maximumsBy(List(("a", 1), ("c", 3), ("c", 3)))(_._2))
  //Output:
  //Some(Vector((c,3), (c,3)))
  //Some(List((c,3), (c,3)))
}
```

I was slightly dismayed by how complex `maximumsBy` ended up. Are there any ways to simplify it, while keeping the same behavior?